# Finished writing my Facebook App, how do I get it into the tab?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm changing from using Static FBML to dynamic pages. The only XFBML tag I'm using is fb:like.

Anyway, it renders fine on my test server, and then again on facebook under the app's URL.

I want to put it on the tab of a Fan page I manage.. how can I get it on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFrames aren't available in tabs yet... you need to use FBML and fb:like is not a valid FBML tag.

They wanted to change this because they are beginning to deprecate FBML. But you should try the iFrame hack instead.

I'm not able to find it on google right now but it works like this:
You create a fb:js-string with the fb:iframe tag in it and then load it in a div as soon as the user clicks something.

Comment: and adding it to ur page is simple. go to the app profil and click on the "add to page" link on the left side

Comment: Here's the fix: http://www.quoture.com/facebook/cant-ad-an-fbml-facebook-app-to-a-tab